# What caused the PersistenceException with the message "detached entity passed to perist"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I'm using:

- Quarkus with JPA (javax)
- Postgres 11 database

I have:

**An Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyEntityTable")
@NamedQuery(name = MyEntity.DOES_EXIST, query = "SELECT x FROM MyEntity x WHERE x.type = :type")
public class MyEntity {

  public static final String DOES_EXIST = "MyEntity.DoesExists";

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "myEntitySequence", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = myEntitySequence)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = type)
  private String type;
}
```

**A repository**

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.Supports)
public class MyEntityReporitory {

  @Inject
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.Required)
  public void persist(final MyEntity entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entiy);
  }

  public boolean doesExist(final String type) {
    final TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = entityManager
      .createNamedQuery(MyEntity.DOES_EXIST, MyEntity.class)
      .setParameter("type", type);
    
    return query.getResultList().size() > 0;
  }
}
```

A test with two variations

**Variation 1**

```java
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(DatabaseResource.class) // used to set up a docker container with postgres db
public class MyEntityRepositoryTest {

  private static final MyEntity ENTITY = entity();

  @Inject
  MyEntityRepository subject;

  @Test
  public void testDoesExist() {
    subject.persist(ENTITY);
    final boolean actual = subject.doesExist("type");
    assertTrue(actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void testDoesExist_notMatching() {
    subject.persist(ENTITY);
    final boolean actual = subject.doesExist("another_type");
    assertFalse(actual);
  }

  private static MyEntity entity() {
    final MyEntity result = new MyEntity();
    result.setType("type")
    return result;
  }
}
```

When I execute this test class (both tests) I'm getting the following Exception on the second time the `persist` method is called:

```java
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist com.mypackage.MyEntity
...
```

**Variation 2**

I removed the constant `ENTITY` from the test class, instead I'm calling now the `entity()` method inside the tests, like:

```java
...
subject.persist(entity());
...
```

at both places. Now the Exeption is gone and everything is fine.

**Question**

Can someone explain to me, why this is the case (why variante 2 is working and variante 1 not)?

Comment: Because in variant 1, your static entity gets an ID during the first test, and Hibernate considers you are trying to persist a detached entity (an entity with an ID but not in the session cache) instead of a new entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/

> The persist operation must be used only for new entities. From JPA perspective, an entity is new when it has never been associated with a database row, meaning that there is no table record in the database to match the entity in question.

1. `testDoesExist` executed, `ENTITY` saved to database and `ENTITY.id` set to 1
2. `testDoesExist_notMatching` executed and persist called on `ENTITY` shows the error beacuse it exists in the database, it has an `id` assigned

The simplest fix is to call `entity()` twice, as in you variation 2.
But don't forget that the records will exist after a test is run, and might affect your other test cases. You might want to consider cleaning up the data in an `@After` method or if you intend to use this entity in multiple test cases then put the perist code into a `@BeforeClass` method.